# I have a lot of selections hanging around. How do I reduce them to a single one?

Tags: kakoune

After any [Kakoune](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune) operation which results in multiple selections (like a global search with `%s`, for example), I get multiple selections and when move up and down or left or right they all move.

How do I get back to having just my primary single selection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to ask on #kakoune @ freenode IRC, the answer is simply <kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Since Kakoune 2022.10.31 it is `,`, not `<space>` anymore.